# Is it possible to make change text directrion with css

Tags: css, html

Is it possible to make text go from top to bottom using css.like? example:

H
E
L
L
O
W
O
R
L
D

It must not be done by adding`<br>` tags in html, and I dont want to rotate the font.

Comment: What does the HTML look like?

Comment: <a class ="test">HELLOWORLD</a>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't want to use either `<br/>` or *rotate the font* then you can achieve the same using this.

CSS

```
.verticle {
    width:10px;
    word-wrap:break-word;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="verticle">
    STACKOVERFLOW
</div>
```

[JsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6RaDX/)

Update: Yes setting `width:0px` solve the problem of smaller letters in one line.

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6RaDX/1/)

Comment: yeah, I was thinking that, but that isn't guaranteed to work in all cases.  for instance, if you changed the text to STiiACKOVERFLOW, the two i's are on the same line.

Comment: Could you just set the width to 0px?

Comment: yeah, width 0 would work.  And then you might need some sort of wrapper to set a real width, depending on the rest of your page layout.

Comment: Wouldn't `1em` work as the width value in this case? I'd add a `text-align: center` as well.